# Symfony Panther - Access a secure iframe?

Tags: php, symfony, security, iframe, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Panther in my Symfony 5 app to fill out a Stripe payment form. My Stripe fields are managed by Stripe itself from iframes generated in my form.

(Take a look on the second example of the Stripe Elements form examples : https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/ , the fields are in Stripe hosted iframe. This is the same thing for my own form)
[image]

[image]

```html
<form>

  // input in main iframe
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='field'>
      <input id="example2-address" data-tid="elements_examples.form.address_placeholder" class="input empty" type="text" placeholder="185 Berry St" required="" autocomplete="address-line1">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  //stripe iframe
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='field'>
      <iframe name='__privateStripeFrame9208'>
        <html>
          <body>
            <form class='ElementsApp is-empty'>
              <input class="InputElement is-empty Input Input--empty" autocomplete="cc-number" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" name="cardnumber" data-elements-stable-field-name="cardNumber" inputmode="numeric" aria-label="Credit or debit card number" placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234" aria-invalid="false" value="">
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```php
//Get iframe
$creditCardFrame = $this->client->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector("#card-number > .__PrivateStripeElement > iframe"));

// returns : "iframe" and "__privateStripeFrame6225"
var_dump($creditCardFrame->getTagName(), $creditCardFrame->getAttribute('name'));

// Switch to iframe. (It should work no ?)
$this->client->switchTo()->frame($creditCardFrame);

// Trying to send keys in my own input (not a stripe field. It's on the default iframe). And I can.
$this->client->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('card-owner'))->sendKeys('my name');

// Trying to send keys in the cardnumber input (in a stripe iframe). Can't locate it.
$this->client->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('cardnumber'))->sendKeys("4242 4242 4242 4242");
```

These iframes seem protected, because when I switch to one of these iframes, it looks like I'm staying on my default frame and I can't access the frame of an input Stripe. In my opinion, this is because these are secure.

I would have liked to give you an error but the problem is that the **switchTo()** method is not programmed to return an error.

The only way to verify that it was successful is to try to fill in a field that is actually in that **iframe**, something I tried, giving me the error

> "Could not locate element ..."

However, if I try to fill in a field that is in **the default iframe**, it works, *which means the iframe change didn't happen.*

As you can see in my code above, I'm making sure I'm pointing to an iframe with this:

```php
// returns : "iframe" and "__privateStripeFrame6225"
var_dump($creditCardFrame->getTagName(), $creditCardFrame->getAttribute('name'));
```

I checked if this was the right way to do it, based on this issue https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/446 , and I don't see why what I would do would be wrong.

So that's why I suspect that the iframe is secure, preventing me from accessing it

Is there a way to access it anyway?

Comment: So when you say "can't access", what exactly goes wrong? An error? Unexpected output? Please be clear and specific. Instead of telling us that something doesn't happen, tell us what you wanted it to do, and then tell us what it actually does instead - that's much more informative.

Comment: I would have liked to give you an error but the problem is that the switchTo () method is not programmed to return an error. The only way to verify that it was successful is to try to fill in a field that is actually in that iframe, something I tried, giving me the error "Could not locate element ..." . However, if I try to fill in a field that is in the default iframe, it works, which means the iframe change didn't happen.

I will update my first post to be clearer. (post updated)

Comment: So it's the first `findElement` call which returns that error, is that correct? Are you certain you have the element name correct? The HTML you showed us doesn't actually make clear what the HTML inside the iframe looks like.

Comment: No, it's the last one.
The 1st `findElement()` returns the element of the iframe to me.

Then the `switchTo()` does not return any error to me.

Then, the second `findElement()` does find the element (but it corresponds to an element present in the main iframe so it doesn't work).

Finally, the last `findElement()` gives me an error "Could not locate element ..."

Regarding the details on the HTML code, you can check the second example at this address: https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

Comment: Sorry but any relevant HTML needs to be shown _here_ in the question. That's how this site works - a complete repository of info relevant to the question, not relying on external resources which might change or disappear, and not relying on volunteers going and poking through a whole great pile of source code to find what you specifically are talking about and already know about. Please put the relevant HTML here for us. Thanks.

Comment: I added an additional image to show. I can't put HTML code there would be way too much just to show the essential it would be unreadable

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the content of a Stripe Elements iframe.  The iframes Stripe Elements uses are designed to prevent you from accessing their content by design in order to [reduce your PCI compliance burden](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) (emphasis added):

> For users that have developed their own integration and are using either  [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout)  or  [Stripe.js and Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js)  to collect card details from customers, you are eligible for the simplest method of PCI validation: SAQ A. Stripe automatically creates a combined SAQ A and Attestation of Compliance (AoC) for you, available for you to download in your account’s  [compliance settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/compliance) , and no action is required on your part to submit further proof of your PCI compliance.
>
> This is possible because **Checkout and Elements host all form inputs containing card data within an iframe served from Stripe’s domain—not yours—so your customers’ card information never touches your servers**.

[Browsers do not allow access to iframes from another origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) by default.  There are [ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to get cross-origin communication working with iframes, but it requires the code inside the iframe to listen for and/or respond to messages sent to it, and Stripe's iframes do not have this code in place.